# Multiple unique replacements in a python string

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to replace fraction with unicode characters by lookup if it in the dictionary but can't find the way to do it.

```
fixs = {
    '1/2': '¹⁄₂',
    '1/4': '¹⁄₄',
    '3/8': '³⁄₈',
     ...
    # '': '⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁄₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉',
}
```

My current solution is obviously bad

```
def fix_fraction(string):
    return string.replace('1/2', '¹⁄₂').replace('1/4', '¹⁄₄').replace('3/8', '³⁄₈')
```

The input of `fix_fraction` might have text mixed in with unknown position so I can't just split the fraction out and I can't write `regex` successfully.

Sample usage:

```
print(fix_fraction('item A d=1/2″'))
print(fix_fraction('item B d=3/8 m'))

item A d=¹⁄₂″                                                                                                                                                                                          
item B d=³⁄₈ m
```

Dictionary is expected to have no more than 100 entries but ultimate solution that support any fraction is also welcomed.

**Any idea how to do this correctly?**

Comment: It can be done using unicode subscripts and superscripts, something like: unichr(0x2070 + v) where v is a digit.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to just loop over your `fixs` and replace items in the text within the loop:

```
In [938]: text = 'item B d=3/8 m'

In [939]: for k in fixs:
     ...:     text = text.replace(k, fixs[k]) 
     ...:     

In [940]: text
Out[940]: 'item B d=³⁄₈ m'
```